# CheckboxModel, pre-selecting rows

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Heys Guys.

I have this error that has been buggin' me for some hours now. I've managed to find the "why", but i need your help to find the "how to fix it".

It's a form for editing a "complex" record.

My Layout is (putting it simply) something like this:

- form

  - tabpanel

    - panel1 (default)

      - ...
      - ...
    - panel2

      - grid

After i create the form, i then proceed to *load* the values of the record into the form and to load to select the rows on the grid, accordingly to the records in a nested store in the record.

And my problem is, because the grid - or the selection model - doesn't have a view (apparently), it throws a  "**Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**"

in

```
onSelectChange: function(record, isSelected, suppressEvent, commitFn) {
    var me      = this,
        views   = me.views,
        viewsLn = views.length, // HERE <-------------
        store   = me.store,
        rowIdx  = store.indexOf(record),
        eventName = isSelected ? 'select' : 'deselect',
        i = 0;
...
```

If I insert a *setTimeout* big enough to change the tab before it tries to **select** the rows, it works ok.

**So, does anyone know how to fix this?** The *setTimeout* approach is not an option, of course :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, problem solved... just selected the rows on the **afterrender** event of the grid.

Might help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when adding the `Ext.form.field.Field` mixin to `Ext.grid.Panel` to create my own `GridMultiSelect` type of form field.  Specifically, I found that the `setValue()` function was being called before the grid was rendered, hence setting the selection failed.

The `setValue()` function may be called both before and after the grid has been rendered, so here's my solution:

```
if (this.rendered) {
    this.getSelectionModel().select(recordsToSelect);
} else {
    this.addListener('afterrender', function() {
        this.getSelectionModel().select(recordsToSelect);
    }, this, {
        single: true
    });
}
```

That is, if it's not yet rendered, create a one-time listener for the `afterrender` event and set the selection then.